VS2022: Unable to change target to WSL2 instance (Echo command failing)
I'm trying to work with VS2022 & CMake while targeting the WSL2 instance following this article. I have an existing Ubuntu-20.04 WSL2 instance that I've been working with for a while now for my C++ builds. My intention is to move my development to the Linux platform, but still use VS2022.
On initial startup of VS2022, I can see that my instances are listed. However, upon selecting the Ubuntu-20.04 instance, it tries to connect but fails with the following output: "Failed to change target system to 'WSL: Ubuntu-20.04': Echo command failing".
The message is not very helpful, and I can't find any other logs that might aid in resolving this. Has anyone encountered this issue before, and also, does anyone know where I can find additional logs or information that could be helpful for debugging this issue?
I've tried looking at the logs at %APP_DATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SettingsLogs but couldn't find information that would be helpful.
Update 20240806:
I managed to enable cross-platform logging, and it generates some information. But it's still not very helpful.
Here's the log
13:02:20.1424797 [Info, Thread 125] liblinux.Local.Services.WslEnumerator: Begin executing: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe --list --verbose
13:02:20.6617777 [Info, Thread 128] liblinux.Local.Services.WslEnumerator: End executing: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe; exitcode: 0; duration: 00:00:00.5202963
13:02:20.6617777 [Info, Thread 133] liblinux.Local.Shell.WindowsSubsystemShell: Connecting to shell at "C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe"
13:02:20.7549560 [Info, Thread 133] liblinux.Local.Shell.WindowsSubsystemShell: VerifyEcho sentinel:17ea8c27-d41f-44cc-a029-dfe6f9bece4c id:fcb0004b-0953-4c2c-8c94-d9b30467b6cb
13:02:20.7549560 [Info, Thread 133] liblinux.Local.Shell.WindowsSubsystemShell: Writing "echo 17ea8c27-d41f-44cc-a029-dfe6f9bece4c" to the fcb0004b-0953-4c2c-8c94-d9b30467b6cb shell
13:02:20.7549560 [Info, Thread 117] liblinux.Local.Shell.WindowsSubsystemShell: Read async: fcb0004b-0953-4c2c-8c94-d9b30467b6cb
13:04:20.7811861 [Info, Thread 133] liblinux.Local.Shell.WindowsSubsystemShell: VerifyEcho failed fcb0004b-0953-4c2c-8c94-d9b30467b6cb
13:04:20.7811861 [Info, Thread 133] liblinux.Local.Shell.WindowsSubsystemShell: Connecting to shell at "C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe"
13:04:20.8947299 [Info, Thread 133] liblinux.Local.Shell.WindowsSubsystemShell: VerifyEcho sentinel:91744b73-d804-476e-a3f1-615091351389 id:fcb0004b-0953-4c2c-8c94-d9b30467b6cb
13:04:20.8947299 [Info, Thread 92]  liblinux.Local.Shell.WindowsSubsystemShell: Read async: fcb0004b-0953-4c2c-8c94-d9b30467b6cb
13:04:20.8947299 [Info, Thread 133] liblinux.Local.Shell.WindowsSubsystemShell: Writing "echo 91744b73-d804-476e-a3f1-615091351389" to the fcb0004b-0953-4c2c-8c94-d9b30467b6cb shell
13:05:20.9045208 [Info, Thread 133] liblinux.Local.Shell.WindowsSubsystemShell: VerifyEcho failed fcb0004b-0953-4c2c-8c94-d9b30467b6cb


It seems like you might have made a typo or I'm not quite sure what you're asking for. Could you please provide more context or clarify your request?

The issue was with my WSL2 image. Using a fresh image of Ubuntu I was able to connect.
